# RxAndroidBle WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT or WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE

Tags: android, android-ble, rxandroidble

I was wondering which strategy the RxAndroidBle library uses regarding write acknowledgements: [WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT) or [WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE)?

Furthermore, should I wish to set (or query) this setting, how might one do this in RxAndroidBle?

I'm in the process of porting an app from RxAndroidBle v1.1 -> v1.2, so am curious if there are any differences to the above questions based on those versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it uses `WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT`. However, you can get a particular characteristic instance (with `getCharacteristic` method) and change it to any value you'd like. There is no convenience method for that.

There is no change in the write type between 1.1 and 1.2.

Cheers!

Comment: Super.  Thanks for clarifying.